# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in ControllerNameController#create SQLite3::SQLException: no such column:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, sqlite

I have a "song" and "artist" model that i have joined via has_many :through relationship. Upon hitting the "create song" i get this persistent error:

- **ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in SongsController#create
  SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: songs.artist: SELECT 1 AS one
  FROM "songs" WHERE ("songs"."name" = 'So much more' AND
  "songs"."artist" IS NULL) LIMIT 1**

Here is the code from the models and view

**song.rb**

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :genre

has_many :artists_songs
has_many :artists, :through => :artists_songs

has_attached_file :image, styles: { large: "600x600>", medium: "300x300>", thumb: "150x150#{}" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

accepts_nested_attributes_for :artists, allow_destroy: true
accepts_nested_attributes_for :artists_songs, allow_destroy: true

validates :name, :presence => true, uniqueness: { scope: :artist } #Unique names in the scope of PARENT
#4now 'featured, description, genre_id, video' is missing because they aren't really a must, the rest perhaps are
validates :year, :lyrics, :country, :image, :presence => true
```

end

**artist.rb**

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :country 

has_many :artists_songs
has_many :songs, :through => :artists_songs

has_attached_file :image, styles: { large: "600x600>", medium: "300x300>", thumb: "150x150#{}" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

validates :name, :presence => true, uniqueness: true
validates :country_id, :image, :presence => true
```

end

**artists_song.rb** The joining model between "Song" and "Artist"

```
class ArtistsSong < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :song
  belongs_to :artist 
end
```

**songs_controller.rb**

```
class SongsController < ApplicationController
before_action :find_song, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def index
    @songs = Song.all
end

def new
    @song = Song.new
    @song.artists.build
    #@genres = Genre.all.map{|c| [ c.name, c.id ] }
end

def create
    @song = Song.new(song_params)
    if @song.save
        redirect_to @song, notice: 'Successfully added a song.'
    else
        render 'index'
    end
end

def show

end

def update
    if @song.update(song_params)
        redirect_to @song, notice: 'Successfully updated the song.'
    else
        render 'edit', notice: 'Unable to save the changes'
    end
end

def edit 
end

def destroy
end

#private methods/functions
private 

#In this private method, the artists attributes are passed to be created via the Song model
def song_params
    params.require(:song).permit(:name, :featured, :year, :lyrics, :description, :video, :image, :genre_id, :artists_song_list, artists_attributes: [ :name, :image, :country_id ])
end

def find_song
    @song = Song.find(params[:id])
end
```

**new.html.erb(-songs_controller)**

```
<div class="content">
<%= form_for @song, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>

    <% if @song.errors.any? %>
        <div>
            <%= @song.errors.count %>
            Prevented this song from saving
            <ul>
                <% @song.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                    <li><%= msg %></li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>

    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name %><br>
    </div>

    <div class="artist-fields">
        <h2>Artist(s)</h2>
        <div class="field">
            <%= f.fields_for :artists do |artists_for_form| %>
                <%= render 'artist_fields', f: artists_for_form %>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="field"> 
        <%= f.label :featured %>
        <%= f.text_field :featured%><br>
    </div>
    <div class="field"> 
        <%= f.label :lyrics %>
        <%= f.text_area :lyrics %><br>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :genre %>
        <%= select_tag(:genre_id, options_for_select(@genres), :prompt => "Select one!") %>
    </div>


    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :description %>
        <%= f.text_area :description %><br>
    </div>  
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :year %>
        <%= f.text_field :year %><br>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :video %>
        <%= f.text_field :video %><br>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :image %>
        <%= f.file_field :image %>
    </div>

    <div class"btn">
        <%= f.submit %> 
    </div>

    <%= link_to "Back", root_path %>

<% end %>
```

What I'm i doing wrong and how do i correctly implement the has_many :through relationship in rails 4?

**column_names for the three tables(Song, Artist, ArtistsSong)**

```
 irb(main):001:0> Song.column_names
 => ["id", "name", "featured", "lyrics", "description", "comments", "created_at", "updated_at", "video", "year", "image_file_name", "image_content_type", "image_file_size", "image_updated_at", "genre_id"]

 irb(main):002:0> Artist.column_names
 => ["id", "name", "created_at", "updated_at", "country_id", "—force", "image_file_name", "image_content_type", "image_file_size", "image_updated_at"]

 irb(main):003:0> ArtistsSong.column_names
=> ["id", "song_id", "artist_id", "created_at", "updated_at"]
```

Comment: did you run your migrations? does your schema.rb reflect the required tables and fields?

Comment: @Alfie yes i did run all the migrations and counter checked the column  names for all the 3 tables.

Comment: + I have appended the console output of each tables column_names...

Comment: Could you also include your error stack trace.

Comment: I'm not to certain, is it the output when run "puts caller" on the terminal or when "Framework trace/ Full Trace" is expanded on the page of the error[localhost:3000]? I'm quite a novice to RoR...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By including the `artists_songs_attributes[:id, artist_id, song_id]` to the *song_params method* in the `songs_controller`, it was possible to successfully add a song with the desired many-to-many relationship between the **song** and **artist** tables through the joining table **artists_song**

Therefore, instead of this:

```
    def song_params
        params.require(:song).permit(:name, :featured, :year, :lyrics, :description, :video, :image, :genre_id, :artists_song_list, artists_attributes: [ :name, :image, :country_id ])
    end
```

this worked:

```
    def song_params
        params.require(:song).permit(:name, :featured, :year, :lyrics, :description, :video, :image, :genre_id, :artists_song_list, artists_attributes: [ :name, :image, :country_id ], artists_songs_attributes[:id, artist_id, song_id])
    end
```

I'm still new and getting to learn the Ruby on Rails framework, hence, according to my little understanding so far, the `artists_songs_attributes [:id, artist_id, song_id]` needed to be passed to the joining table (**artists_song**) to create the row(s) that actually creates the link between the created row(s) of the two tables (**artist** &  **song**).